# Get-WindowsUpdateLog stream re-direction

Tags: powershell

Has anyone noticed how the `Get-WindowsUpdateLog` cmdlet cannot be redirected to any streams?

Furthermore, storing the output into a variable, piping it, or any type of re-direction leads to the cmdlet to **only** be executed.

Any help redirecting/silencing the output of this command would be appreciated.

What I've tried:

```
Get-WindowsUpdateLog | Out-Null

Get-WindowsUpdateLog > $null

$sink = Get-WindowsUpdateLog
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the output?

Comment: The output needs to be silenced/nulled. To answer your question, I want to effectively eliminate the output from ever displaying.

Comment: I found a suggestion by @PetSerAl `&{Set-Alias Out-Default Out-Null; Get-WindowsUpdateLog ...}` [here](https://superuser.com/q/1058117) that might help.

Comment: Weird.  Even `*>$null` doesn't work with it.

Comment: I think the lesson here is don't use `Out-Default` in a script.  https://keithga.wordpress.com/2018/04/03/out-default-considered-harmful/  I don't see that command in powershell 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything I could find failed to suppress the output of the CmdLet `Get-WindowsUpdateLog`. As you say, the displayed information in the console is not properly following the output streams as we know them in `PowerShell`.

The only workaround I found is using `Jobs`:

```
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Get-WindowsUpdateLog}
$Job | Wait-Job | Remove-Job
```

This way all output is handled within the job and we don't retrieve the result. It's also unnecessary to retrieve it as the result is simply a text file placed in the `-Path` parameter.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Found it myself a few hours ago, but marking this as the correct one, since you posted it first :)

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to DarkLite's answer, we can also utilise the following code to check if `Get-WindowsUpdateLog` cmdlet worked properly :

```
# Generate a unique filename.            
$o_filename = "C:\temp\" + "WindowsUpdateLog" + "_" + ( Get-Date -UFormat "%H_%M_%S" ) + ".txt"

$o_job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-WindowsUpdateLog -LogPath "$( $args[0] )" } `
                   -ArgumentList $o_filename -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

$o_job | Remove-Job -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if( ! ( Test-Path $o_filename ) ) {
#       Return an exception
}
else {
#       Do some work on the generated log file  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the lesson here is don't use Out-Default in a script. https://keithga.wordpress.com/2018/04/03/out-default-considered-harmful/ I don't see that command in powershell 6.  But it is in powershell 7!